# After transferring file.spydata from pc to pc import in spyder wont work?

Tags: python, import, spyder

I got a new Laptop and transferred my python project to this new Laptop. Now, when I want to import the file.spydata file into my python project in spyder it does nothing. I get no log messages or anything.

Do you know how to import those files into spyder? Whether they be corrupted through the transfer (that is quite impossible because it affects all those files)?

Comment: Are you saving those files in Python 2 and try to import them in Python 3?

Comment: No both are saved in python 3 because I use it with tensorflow. The only difference is that i set up tensorflow with a gpu instead of cpu.

Comment: How big is your spydata file?

Comment: The size is eg. about 78MB. (Sorry for the delay.)

Comment: Are you importing it between different operating systems (e.g. Linux to Windows)?

Comment: No it is both windows 7.

Comment: Sorry for not being more helpful, I don't know what's happening in your case. I can only say that this is a not so well tested functionality in Spyder, so you should be better by not depending on it for now (we plan to improve it in Spyder 4).

Comment: Thanks for understanding!